# Split String for nested Struct type Schema using Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, struct

I am trying to split an input of String using Regex pattern.

```
String input = "id string,name string,balances struct<netincome:decimal(10,4),grossincome:decimal(10,4)," +
               "ledger:struct<id:int,month:string>>";

String seperatorRegex = ",((?![^<>]*\\>)(?![^()]*\\)))";

String[] splitInput = input.split(seperatorRegex);
```

**Expected output -**

```
"id string"
"name string"
"balances struct<netincome:decimal(10,4),grossincome:decimal(10,4),ledger:struct<id:int,month:string>>"
```

But using the above code I am getting the below output -

```
"id string"
"name string"
"balances struct<netincome:decimal(10,4)"
"grossincome:decimal(10,4),ledger:struct<id:int,month:string>>"
```

Please suggest me how to achieve the desired output.

The above regex is working fine for below input -

```
String input = "id string,name string,balances struct<netincome:decimal(10,4),grossincome:decimal(10,4)>";
```

But for nested type Struct means Struct inside Struct(<:<:>>), it is not working. I have analyzed that when "<" is coming in the middle, the regex is not working.

Comment: Please don't mark this question as a duplicate. The regex of the split operation should be different.

Comment: Can you define your rules for splitting on comma?

Comment: I want to split using "," but I don't want to split those "," which are inside of the "<>" and "()"

Comment: String input = "id string,name string,balances struct<netincome:decimal(10,4),grossincome:decimal(10,4)>"; 

This is working fine. But getting the problem for nested struct.

Comment: Might be doable using match, let me find out.

Comment: @sln We can resolve for () and <>. But the problem is arising for <:<:>>.